# Pull User Info From AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to pull a list of users (first name and last), their email addresses, and which container they're in, but unfortunately it's not coming up with the data I need.  I can get most of the information, just not the container name.

```
Get-ADUser -SearchBase 'DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=COM' -Filter {(mail -ne "null") -and (Enabled -eq "true")} -Properties emailAddress |
    Select givenName,surName,OU,emailAddress |
    Format-Table -AutoSize |
    Out-File 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Lists\Users_List.txt'
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for the attribute `DistinguishedName`, but to just get the OU you would have to do some formatting. If you ran `Get-ADUser | Get-Member` you would see there is no property called OU.

```
Get-ADUser `
   -SearchBase 'DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=COM' `
   -Filter {(mail -ne "null") -and (Enabled -eq "true")} `
   -Properties emailAddress `
| Select givenName,surName,@{Name='OU';Expression={$_.DistingishedName.Replace("CN=$($_.Name),","")}},emailAddress `
| Format-Table -AutoSize `
| Out-File 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\Lists\Users_List.txt'
```

Article on [Understanding PowerShell Custom Properties with the Select-Object cmdlet](https://www.petri.com/understanding-powershell-custom-properties-with-select-object-cmdlet)

Comment: Thank you for the advice on using "DistinguishedName".  I'm able to find the information needed - however more than what I want, so I'll have to work on filtering it down to what I'm needing.

However, now I've run into a new issue.  Because I'm exporting the information into a text file, there's a character limit per line.  Know of any way to get around this?  I would prefer to export it into a CSV file, but I couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: I tried the above script, as you have it formatted, however, my results are as followed:

"givenName","surName","OU","emailAddress"

"Alan","Adams",,"aadams@domainaddress.com"

But when I modify my code to include the "DistinguishedName" it retrieves the information.  Is there a way to filter out the unneeded info such as the "CN=Info" and "DC=info"?

Comment: You're starting to drill down to having me write your script for you. The function `Export-Csv` works for me pretty much every time so you could use it instead of `Format-Table` & `Out-File`. That would get your information into a .csv format. If you just wanted the name of the OU you could just select the first OU name with the regex OR you could take the string I used in my expression, pass it to `Get-ADOrganizationalUnit` and select the Name property of it.

Comment: I found out what I was doing wrong with Export-CSV.  Turns out that I was using the "Format-Table" which won't work for what I needed to do.

Sorry, wasn't trying to get you to write my script for me, but my focus is bounced between five different projects right now including on-call support.  So any support I can get right now is a huge help.  Time isn't really on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I would change your mail filters to $false, and $true.  I don't have a computer with the AD module installed on it to test out my answer, otherwise I would have provided more.